# Inability to loop through the whole range of values during web-scrape exercise using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have the following lines of code:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('screener-link-primary')
y = 21
x = 1
list_of_tickers = []

while x < 10:
    for element in elements:
        list_of_tickers.append(element.get_attribute('text'))

    next_button = 'a[href="screener.ashx?v=111&o=-marketcap&r={}"]'.format(y)
    click_next_page = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_button))).click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, elements)))

    x = x + 1
    y = y + 20
```

I am trying to scrape a website and extract all the elements until I go to another page. My code makes it to the second page, but it gets stuck and can't proceed on the 3 pages. I do not know what is causing the mistake, but every time I run the code, I experience a TimeoutException: Message: error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the link to the website you're trying to extract data from?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an issue.

This variable

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('screener-link-primary')
```

was outside of the main loop, so it didn't absorb new elements as the code moved to the next page, so the error was occurring.

Once I put 'elements' variable into the main loop (starting with while), the code has ran errorless.